# SEVERE: Servlet /SAIRAM-SERVICE threw load() exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat6, java-6

I have written a simple Hello World restful web service. I have used the tomcat 6 and jdk1.6, and ID e Juno Service Release 1, jersey-core-1.0.2,jsr311-api-1.0,asm-3.1,jersey-server-1.0.2 jars included in my build path. when i run the server i am getting the below exception

Could any body help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not
>   able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during
>   compile time. For example if we have a method call from a class or
>   accessing any static member of a Class and that class is not available
>   during run-time then JVM will throw NoClassDefFoundError.
>
> Read more:
>   http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#ixzz2o0WtFtEx

This is extracted from [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) which also provide 3 general ways to solve this error.